# Mysql Join 2 Table and merge 2 Column, But remove Duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Table from where I want customerid, customername, comment and customercontactno.

I use Following query For Join 2 Table.

```
SELECT comment.id, comment.Kommentar, comment.Kunde,
CONCAT_WS('', customer.telefonPrivat, customer.TelefonMobil) AS Contact_Phone 
FROM tbl_test_comment comment 
LEFT JOIN tbl_test_customer customer 
ON customer.id = comment.Kunde;
```

My First table is **tbl_test_comment** With following data

[image]

And **tbl_test_customer**

[image]

**Result Of Above Query**

[image]

**ISSUE**

When I run above query, Its working fine if one of two merged column is empty. But it merge data if data are in both row. I want to avoid one if both row have value.

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Be more clear please.

Comment: @Ullas I join 2 table and merge two column which contain contact number. but When both contact no. column have value, then do not merge. currently it merge both contact no.

Comment: Please add expected output to your post.

Answer (score 1):

`concat_ws` stands for "concatenate with separator", that is, add the strings together with the separator in between.

Instead, use the `coalesce` function, which returns the first non-null argument:

```
coalesce(customer.telefonPrivat, customer.TelefonMobil)
```

If an empty telephone number can be an empty string `''` as well as `null`, you can use the more powerful `case` statement:

```
case 
when length(customer.telefonPrivat) > 0 then customer.telefonPrivat
else customer.TelefonMobil
end
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I want. But If "telefonPrivat" is null then it does not select TelefonMobil. How do I prevent this ?

Comment: But it should. There is a difference between NULL and ''

Comment: Perhaps you have empty string instead of nulls?  I'll update the answer